# Sum particular list values

Tags: python, list

I want to sum 3d list values by first two criteria.
What is the best way to get from this list

```
a = [['Mercedes', 'AMG', 100],
['Mercedes', 'Cabrio', 200],
['Mercedes', 'AMG', 300],
['Opel', 'Combo', 400],
['Opel', 'MOKKA', 500],
['Opel', 'MOKKA', 600],
['BMW', 'X5', 700]]
```

this result:

```
result = [['Mercedes', 'AMG', 400],
['Mercedes', 'Cabrio', 200],
['Opel', 'Combo', 400],
['Opel', 'MOKKA', 1100],
['BMW', 'X5', 700]]
```

Comment: Do you have pandas? This is a more suited to that. Indeed, it's only one operation.

Comment: nope. I dont have pandas and Im looking for a pure python way to do this

Comment: So you should please try something first, post your code and tell us what the problem is.

Comment: No problem here. Just looking for some better solution than I could make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be using an `OrderedDict` to perform aggregation.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
for x, y, z in a:
     d[(x, y)] = d.setdefault((x, y), 0) + z

r = [list(k) + [v] for k, v in d.items()]   
r

[['Mercedes', 'AMG', 400],
 ['Mercedes', 'Cabrio', 200],
 ['Opel', 'Combo', 400],
 ['Opel', 'MOKKA', 1100],
 ['BMW', 'X5', 700]]
```

Comment: I was going to up-vote but SO is not a place to give free solutions.

Comment: @ElisByberi Maybe... I usually VTC/dupe, but I'm out of close votes, and out of up/down votes, so no other option ;-)

Comment: Encourage OP to give it a try and do not give a solution, give an answer to his problem. In this particular case, the answer would be "The problem you have is that you have not write a single line of code. How would you except it without code?"

Comment: @ElisByberi I'm well aware, I've been doing this for quite a while now. It's just that, sometimes, you feel like taking a break and flexing your coding skills instead of your policing.

Comment: It's the thrill of the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you can do if you are not concerned about order:

```
set_list = set(map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1]), a))

result = [
    [m[0], m[1], sum([y[2] for y in a if (y[0], y[1]) == m])] 
    for m in set_list
]
```

Comment: You lose order though.

Comment: Can't lose `order` if it's a dictatorship comrade.

Comment: Well, that's enough internet for one day.